Was the term " these little ones" used as a code word for believers?
Jesus used the attribute "these little ones" for his followers. We see a mention of the term first in 2 Chronicles 31:18, which says:

They included all the little ones, the wives, and the sons and daughters of the whole community listed in these genealogical records. For they were faithful in consecrating themselves.

Coming to NT, we read, for example, in Matthew 10:42, which says:

And if anyone gives even a cup of cold water to one of these little ones who is my disciple, truly I tell you, that person will certainly not lose their reward.”

My question is: was the term "these little ones" used as a code word for believers?

Barnes' Notes on the Bible says on Matthew 18:6:

These little ones - That is, Christians manifesting the spirit of
little children, 1 John 2:1, 1 John 2:12, 1 John 2:18, 1 John 2:28.

The Pulpit Commentary says on Matthew 18:6:

One of these little ones. Whether child or adult, a pure, simple soul,
which has a certain faith it be not strong enough to resist all
attack.



It seems to be quite generally assumed that at least in some of the instances of its occurrence the phrase designates, quite simply, actual children. (Matthew 18:10, Mark 9:37, Luke 9:48)

“little ones” was also used by Jesus as an affectionate designation for His disciples. (Matthew 10:42, Matthew 18:6, Matthew 18:10, Matthew 18:14, Mark 9:42, Luke 17:2)


Jesus also used “little ones” for His followers, similar to other terms like “children of the kingdom”, “sheep”, and “little flock”.

Sheep: Matthew 26:31, John 10:7, John 10:16
Little flock: Luke 12:32
Children: Mark 10:24, John 21:5
Little children: John 13:33
Flock: Matthew 26:31, John 10:16
Lambs: Luke 10:3, John 21:15

I conclude then that, while I wouldn't classify “these little ones” as a secret code word, it is a term that Jesus uses to describe actual little children and His followers, particularly those who are humble and have child-like faith.




Reference:





Little ones - Hastings’ Dictionary of the New Testament -. (n.d.). StudyLight.org. https://www.studylight.org/dictionaries/eng/hdn/l/little-ones.html




Believers in the Bible are often compared to children. The Bible makes several references that true believers should be like children:

He called a little child and had him stand among them.And he said: "I tell you the truth, unless you change and become like little children, you will never enter the kingdom of heaven.Therefore, whoever humbles himself like this child is the greatest in the kingdom of heaven. (Matthew 18:2-4)

Further on in Matthew 18:6 another reference is made:

But if anyone causes one of these little ones who believe in me to sin, it would be better for him to have a large millstone hung around his neck and to be drowned in the depths of the sea.

So if by code you mean, "little ones" is a reference to believers absolutely. Jesus often spoke in metaphors and parables, but I don't think He had any need to disguise the fact that He was referring to believers, like ppl who were living under heavy censorship for example and needed alternative terms to refer to these things (ie euphemisms). Is "little ones" used often as a reference to Christians and believers thematically throughout the Bible? I think my quotes combined with yours absolutely establishes that without a doubt.

+1. Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Yukai! We're glad you're here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

"These little ones" is a technical phrase, used only by Jesus, as a phrase of endearment describing literal children who are children of Christians.  It occurs in the following places in the NT

Matt 10:42 - And if anyone gives even a cup of cold water to one of these little ones because he is My disciple, truly I tell you, he will never lose his reward.”
Matt 18:6 - But if anyone causes one of these little ones who believe in Me to stumble, it would be better for him to have a large millstone hung around his neck and to be drowned in the depths of the sea.
Matt 18:10 - See that you do not look down on any of these little ones. For I tell you that their angels in heaven always see the face of My Father in heaven.
Matt 18:14 - In the same way, your Father in heaven is not willing that any of these little ones should perish.
Mark 9:42 - But if anyone causes one of these little ones who believe in Me to stumble, it would be better for him to have a large millstone hung around his neck and to be thrown into the sea.
Luke 17:2 - It would be better for him to have a millstone hung around his neck and to be thrown into the sea than to cause one of these little ones to stumble.

In all cases, the term "these little ones" refers to actual children as the most helpless and needy of all Christ's followers.
Thus, it is established that Jesus' teaching had as one of its tenants:

that children are as important as adults and just as worthy of the kingdom as anyone
that God cares for children as much as adults

For the time (1st century) this was a radical idea and not always fully appreciated and adopted by the Christian church.
